# How do I create a dictionary with keys from a list and values separate empty lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Building from [How do I create a dictionary with keys from a list and values defaulting to (say) zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869487/how-do-i-create-a-dictionary-with-keys-from-a-list-and-values-defaulting-to-say)
and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870244/2436175):

**How do I create a dictionary with keys from a list and values separate empty lists?**
(Where, later on, I'll be able to append elements)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension,

```
{item: [] for item in my_list}
```

You are simply iterating the list and creating a new list for every key.

Alternatively, you can think about using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for item in my_list:
    d[item].append(whatever_value)
```

Here, the function object which we pass to `defaultdict` is the main thing. It will be called to get a value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answered beyond my narrow question, addressing the complete problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and easy implementation , It is self explaining , we iterate over all the elements in the list and create a unique entry in the dictionary for each value and initialize it with an empty list

```
sample_list = [2,5,4,6,7]
sample_dict = {}
for i in sample_list:
    sample_dict[i] = []
```

Answer (score -1):

By normal method:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in l:
...   d[i] = []
... 
>>> d
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
>>>
```

---

By using `collections` module

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in l:
...   d[i]
... 
[]
[]
[]
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []})
```