# Calculating number of unique co-authors in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a really large dataframe with Book ID's and the names of people that have co-authored each book together. I want to calculate how many "unique" co-authors every author has ever worked with in his **entire career**.

For example:

```
BookID   Author
  1         John
  1         Alex
  1         Jenna
  2         John
  2         Alex
  3         John
  4         Alex
  4         Mary
  4         Max
```

The expected result would be (what's between parenthesis isn't required but I put it there to better justify, I just want the number):

```
Author     Num_Unique_CoAuthors
 John           2                    (Alex and Jenna)
 Alex           4                    (John, Jenna, Mary and Max)
 Jenna          2                    (Alex and John)
 Mary           2                    (Alex and Max)
 Max            2                    (Alex and Mary)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create `set`s per groups to new column, then get difference with `Author` column, remove empty sets by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last flatten values to new sets for unique, last get length:

```
df = df.join(df.groupby('BookID')['Author'].apply(set).rename('new'), 'BookID')

df['new'] = [b - set([a]) for a, b in zip(df['Author'], df['new'])]

df = (df[df['new'].astype(bool)].groupby('Author')['new']
          .apply(lambda x: tuple(set([z for y in x for z in y])))
          .to_frame())

df.insert(0, 'Num_Unique_CoAuthors', df['new'].str.len())
print (df)
        Num_Unique_CoAuthors                       new
Author                                                
Alex                       4  (Max, John, Jenna, Mary)
Jenna                      2              (John, Alex)
John                       2             (Jenna, Alex)
Mary                       2               (Max, Alex)
Max                        2              (Mary, Alex)
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: How would I edit this to include authors with zero co-authors? I want to include empty sets in this case.

Comment: @BKS - try remove change `df[df['new'].astype(bool)]` to `df`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

First groupby `BookID` and [list all authors per book (i.e. list all authors per group)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53088007/4057186)

```
combos = df.groupby('BookID').agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index(drop=False)
print(combos)
   BookID               Author
0       1  [John, Alex, Jenna]
1       2         [John, Alex]
2       3               [John]
3       4    [Alex, Mary, Max]
```

Next, merge back with main data, on `BookID`, to get all authors for each author

```
merged = combos.merge(df, how='inner', on='BookID')
print(merged)
   BookID             Author_x Author_y
0       1  [John, Alex, Jenna]     John
1       1  [John, Alex, Jenna]     Alex
2       1  [John, Alex, Jenna]    Jenna
3       2         [John, Alex]     John
4       2         [John, Alex]     Alex
5       3               [John]     John
6       4    [Alex, Mary, Max]     Alex
7       4    [Alex, Mary, Max]     Mary
8       4    [Alex, Mary, Max]      Max
```

`Author_x` is the full author list and includes `Author_y`. It is now possible to compare the full author list (`Author_x`) with each individual/unique author (`Author_y`), with the following approach

1. [Create dict whose keys are unique `Author_y` values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869503/4057186) (i.e. unique authors) and values are blank lists
2. Iterate over each key-value pair in dict
3. slice merged dataframe from above step using `Author_y` column; this gives all authors for the author in the dict key
4. from slice, get list of all authors (`Author_x`) as flattened list
5. [extend blank list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/4057186) with [difference between flattened list (all authors) and dict key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462160/4057186)

```
d = {auth:[] for auth in df['Author'].unique()}
for k,v in d.items():
    all_auths = merged[merged['Author_y']==k]['Author_x'].values.tolist()
    auths = [coauths for nested in all_auths for coauths in nested]
    v.extend(list(set(auths) - set([k])))
```

Finally, put into `DataFrame` and count the non-null values per row

```
cnames = ['coauth'+str(k) for k in range(1,len(d))]
df_summary = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=cnames)
df_summary['Num_Unique_CoAuthors'] = df_summary.shape[1] - df_summary.isna().sum(axis=1)
print(df_summary)
  author coauth1 coauth2 coauth3 coauth4  Num_Unique_CoAuthors
0   John    Alex   Jenna    None    None                     2
1   Alex     Max    John    Mary   Jenna                     4
2  Jenna    John    Alex    None    None                     2
3   Mary     Max    Alex    None    None                     2
4    Max    Alex    Mary    None    None                     2
```

**Extended data case**

If the main data contains a single author (i.e. without any co-authors), then this method prints zero for that row

Here is a dummy row added to the data, with a single author

```
print(df)
   BookID Author
0       1   John
1       1   Alex
2       1  Jenna
3       2   John
4       2   Alex
5       3   John
6       4   Alex
7       4   Mary
8       4    Max
9       5    Tom
```

And here is the output

```
  author coauth1 coauth2 coauth3 coauth4  Num_Unique_CoAuthors
0   John   Jenna    Alex    None    None                     2
1   Alex    Mary    John   Jenna     Max                     4
2  Jenna    John    Alex    None    None                     2
3   Mary     Max    Alex    None    None                     2
4    Max    Mary    Alex    None    None                     2
5    Tom    None    None    None    None                     0
```

**Initial Answer**

Did you try a `groupby` with `sum` aggregation

```
df.groupby(['Author'])['BookID'].sum()
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just give us how many books he's written? Not how many co-authors he has?

Comment: Also the numbers under Book ID are just IDs, they might as well be strings. Shouldn't be treated as integers, so using sum wouldn't make sense. :)

Comment: @BKS, thanks for your comments here. I have updated this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution.

1. Join on `BookID`
2. Create an adjacency matrix using [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)
3. Tally up the counts along the rows, not including the author of the row.

---

```
>>> df_merge = df.merge(df, on='BookID')
>>> ctdf = pd.crosstab(df_merge.Author_x, df_merge.Author_y, aggfunc='max', values=[1] * len(df_merge)).fillna(0)
>>> ctdf
Author_y  Alex  Jenna  John  Mary  Max
Author_x
Alex       1.0    1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0
Jenna      1.0    1.0   1.0   0.0  0.0
John       1.0    1.0   1.0   0.0  0.0
Mary       1.0    0.0   0.0   1.0  1.0
Max        1.0    0.0   0.0   1.0  1.0
>>> ctdf.apply(lambda x: sum([*x]) - 1)
Author_y
Alex     4.0
Jenna    2.0
John     2.0
Mary     2.0
Max      2.0
dtype: float64
```